# Best Method to Switch Between Terms (Custom Taxonomy)

Tags: custom-taxonomy, conditional-tags, conditional-content, customization

Looking to learn something, here.

With the following code, I am loading an external file for each condition based on a known set of custom terms.  I'm using has_terms to check for a specific value within the custom tax 'delivery_option'.

```
$taxonomy = 'delivery_option';

        if(has_term( 'public-delivery', $taxonomy ) ){
           include_once( CHILD_THEME_DIR . '/includes/sidebar-part-public.php');
        } elseif (has_term('onsite-delivery', $taxonomy ) ){
            include_once( CHILD_THEME_DIR . '/includes/sidebar-part-onsite.php');
        } elseif (has_term('online-delivery', $taxonomy ) || has_term('self-directed-delivery', $taxonomy ) ){
            include_once( CHILD_THEME_DIR . '/includes/sidebar-part-online.php');
        } else {
          echo '<p>No custom include!</p>'
        }
```

It works.  But is this the best/most efficient way to do this?  I looked into possibly using a 'switch', but I'm not sure how that would work.... 'has_term' seems much more efficient than some method that returns term objects before checking them.

These terms are hierarchical and should be mutually exclusive. Any one post will have one delivery option.

Advice? Looking for best practice recommendation or affirmation that I'm not out of line. :)

Comment: I see that a part of your file name is each time the same as a part of the term name. So maybe it is an idea to use the term name in your included file name? Or you can "map" the files and terms into a wp option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am reading your code and description correctly, you can simplify that to:

```
$taxonomy = 'delivery_option';
$do = get_the_terms($post->ID,$taxonomy);
if (!empty($do) && !is_wp_error($do)) {
  $do = array_shift($do); //  assuming a single value as per the description.
  $term = str_replace('-delivery','',$do->slug);
  get_template_part('includes/sidebar-part',$term);
} else {
  echo '<p>No custom include!</p>';
}
```

Note, I used WordPress's `get_template_part()` instead of PHP's `include()` as that is the more correct way to include template files.

Comment: This definitely looks like a much better method! Very tight.  However, it's throwing an error for me: "Trying to get property of non-object" on the $term = str_replace line.

Comment: I kinda did this without testing ;) What is `var_dump($do);`?

Comment: `array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#516 (11) { ["term_id"]=> int(101) ["name"]=> string(20) "Public & On-Site" ["slug"]=> string(15) "public-delivery" ["term_group"]=> int(0) ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(101) ["taxonomy"]=> string(15) "delivery_option" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["parent"]=> int(0) ["count"]=> int(59) ["object_id"]=> int(7783) ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } } `

Comment: @philensminger : try the edit.

Comment: BOOM! Works perfectly.

Comment: Followup: Am I correct that an include named sidebar-part.php would be used for any post that did not call a more specific file (using the ,$term call above), and that I should create this file as a fallback?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I don't think the code would get that far along.

Comment: Ah. Okay. That shouldn't be an issue anyway as the use of this custom taxonomy is limited to this set of terms.

I'll have to read up on `get_template_part()`.  This is exactly what I hoped to learn by posting here.  Thank you so much.